# I have used react-router for my single-page-application. why my page is getting refreshed after navigating to another page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React-redux, I am using react-router to make my application SINGLE PAGE APP. Routing is working fine but page is getting refreshed. Means when I navigate from one page to another there is a page refresh.  I have worked on angular application. I did not see page refresh in angular based app.  Is it correct behavior of react-router (page refresh on navigation)?

Comment: The page doesn't refresh with react router only the component that is changed is refreshed. Pls Share your code for react-router. Maybe you are redirecting the wrong way.

Comment: Are you using the `Link` component for navigation or `a href="<url_here>">`?  You want to be using `Link`

Answer (score 2):

Try their [examples](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples), those are easy to understand. No, it doesn't reload. 
You can use `<Link>` or you can set the URL with history push, there are many options.

[Simple Example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/active-links/app.js)

Answer (score 1):

You must be using anchor tags in your reactjs code. You need to use  tag instead  tag.

So use  `import {Link} from react-router` and then in places where you have anchor tag replace it with Link tag.

For example:-

```
<a href="example.com">click here</a>
```

Change above to

```
<Link to="example.com">click here</Link>
```